# Problema con acceso a módulos de programa PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Llevo un rato trabajando en este código y no he podido solucionar la situación, me funciona cuando lo pruebo en *localhost*, pero a la hora de subirlo a 1&1 me resulta un error en el cual me dice a la vez que no tengo acceso al sistema y luego me envía el mensaje de bienvenida al usuario antes de reenviarme al *index* y no me permite acceder a los módulos del programa.

```
<?php

class ModeloConect
{
    private $servidor = 'xxx'
    private $usuario = 'xxx';
    private $clave = 'xxx';
    private $bd = 'xxx';
    protected $laRow = array();
    private $con;
    private $res;


    protected function conectar()
    {
        $this->con=mysqli_connect($this->servidor,$this->usuario,$this->clave);
        mysqli_select_db($this->con, $this->bd);
    }

    protected function desconectar()
    {
        mysqli_close($this->con);
    }


    //FUNCION PROTEGIDA FILTRO DE BUSQUEDA
    protected function filtro($sql)
    {
        $lrTb=mysqli_query($this->con, $sql) OR die(mysqli_error($this->con));
        return $lrTb;
    }

    //FUNCION PROTEGIDA CIERRAFILTRO DE BUSQUEDA
    protected function cierrafiltro($result)
    {
       mysqli_free_result($result);
    }

    protected function ejecutar($sql)
    {
        $this->res=mysqli_query($this->con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($this->con));
        if (mysqli_affected_rows($this->con)==0)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    //FUNCION PROXIMO PARA RECORRER result PROXIMA POSICION DEL ARRAY
    protected function proximo($result)
    {
        $laRow=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        return $laRow;
    }

    //FUNCION PROTEGIDA NUMERO DE REGISTROS PARA SABER LA CANTIDAD DE REGISTROS EXISTENTES
    protected function num_registros($result)
    {  
        $lnRegistros=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        return $lnRegistros;
    }

    //FUNCION BEGIN
    protected function begin()
    {
        mysqli_query($this->con, "BEGIN");
    }

    //FUNCION COMMIT
    protected function commit()
    {
        mysqli_query($this->con, "COMMIT");
    }

    //FUNCION ROLLBACK
    protected function rollback()
    {
        mysqli_query($this->con, "ROLLBACK");
    }

    protected function formato_fecha($pcFecha)
    {
        $lcNow=date("Y-m-d");
        if (strlen($pcFecha)==10)
        {
            $lcDia=substr($pcFecha,0,2);
            $lcMes=substr($pcFecha,3,2);
            $lcAno=substr($pcFecha,6,4);
            $lcNow=$lcAno."-".$lcMes."-".$lcDia;
        }
        return $lcNow;
    }

}
?>
```

Este es el módulo de conectividad general que funciona como núcleo del sistema para las conexiones con la base de datos.

Luego el módulo de control de acceso se ve así:

```
<?php

    session_start();//inicia la session, la cual permite trabajar con la variable $_SESSION
    require_once('../clases/clase_usuario.php');//Trae el archivo clase_usuario.php para instanciarlo
    $lobjUsuario= new clsUsuario;//Instancia la clase clsUsuario en $lobjUsuario, para poder usar sus metodos y atributos 

    $usuario=$_POST['usuario'];//Captura los datos enviados desde el campo USUARIO en la vista del index.php
    $clave=$_POST['clave'];//Captura los datos enviados desde el campo CLAVE en la vista del index.php

    $lobjUsuario->set_Usuario($usuario);//Envia el dato USUARIO a la clase clsUsuario Mediante el metodo SET_
    $lobjUsuario->set_Clave($clave);//Envia el dato CLAVE a la clase clsUsuario Mediante el metodo SET_
    //En esta serie de IF() se intenta determinar desde donde fue accionado o llamado este archivo, si desde el index con el botón ENTRAR o desde la intranet con el botón SALIR.
    if($_POST['entrar'])//Si es desde el botón ENTRAR ingresa en la condición.
    {
        $datosUsuario=$lobjUsuario->login();//Como los datos ya fueron enviados a la clase, el solo tiene que ejecutar la funcion login() de la clase ClsUsuario, para verificar los datos del usuario.
        if($datosUsuario[0])//si lo datos son correctos entonces entra en la condición para guardar los datos en variables $_SESSION
        {
            $_SESSION['usuario']=$datosUsuario[0]; //Se guarda el nombre de usuario con el cual ingresó.
            $_SESSION['nombrerol']=$datosUsuario[1];//Se guarda el nombre del rol que tiene asignado ese usuario.
            $_SESSION['idrol']=$datosUsuario[2];//Se guarda el ID del rol.
            $_SESSION['cedulaper']=$datosUsuario[3];//Se guarda la cedula del usuario.
            $_SESSION['msj']='Bienvedido al sistema '.$datosUsuario[0].'.';//Se guarda un mensaje, que posterior mente será borrado.
            header('location: ../vista/intranet.php');//Y se redirecciona al archivo intranet.php
        }
        else //Si el usuario no existe o es incorrecto el usuario y/o clave este es sacado del sistema
        {

            $_SESSION['msj']='El usuario y/o clave que ingresó son incorrectos.'; //Se guarda un mensaje, que posterior mente será borrado.
            header('location: ../intranet.php');//Y se redirecciona al archivo index.php
        }
    }
    elseif($_POST['salir'])// Si el usuario ingresó aquí a traves de la intranet por medio del botón SALIR, entonces entrará en esta condicion.
    {
            session_destroy();//Desctruye los datos de la sessión que guardamos cuando ENTRÓ en el sistema.
            session_start();//Se crea una session solo para que pueda ser guardado el mensaje de despedida.
            $_SESSION['msj']='Hasta pronto! Su sesión ha sido cerrada.';//Se guarda un mensaje, que posterior mente será borrado.
            header('location: ../intranet.php');//Y se redirecciona al archivo index.php
    }
    else //Si no entro por ningun botón o hubo un error entonces lo va a sacar.
    { 
            $_SESSION['msj']='Disculpe ha habido un error.';//Se guarda un mensaje, que posterior mente será borrado.
            header('location: ../intranet.php');//Y se redirecciona al archivo index.php
    }


?>
```

Acá aparece el mensaje de bienvenida que debería aparecer primero, pero aparece en segunda instancia antes de retornarme a *index*.

Por último, esta página me debería redirigir a esta página, donde aparece el segundo mensaje:

```
<?php

    session_start(); //inicia la session, la cual permite trabajar con la variable $_SESSION

    $usuario=(isset($_SESSION['usuario']))?$_SESSION['usuario']:"";//toma el valor que se guarda en la variable vista que está en la variable $_SESSION
    $msj=(isset($_SESSION['msj']))?$_SESSION['msj']:"";//toma el valor que se guarda en la variable vista que está en la variable $_SESSION
    $vista=(isset($_GET['vista']))?$_GET['vista']:"";//toma el valor que se guarda en la variable vista que está en la URL.
    if(!$usuario)  //verifica si existe algún usuario logueado en el arreglo usuario de la variable $_SESSION
    {
      echo '<script>alert("Acceso Denegado! Usted no tiene una sesión iniciada en el sistema.");window.location.href="../index.php";</script>'; // Si no existe un usuario logeado entonces le mostraŕa un mensaje y lo sacará para el inicio! 
    }
    if($msj)  //verifica si existe algún texto en el arreglo msj de la variable $_SESSION
    {
        echo '<script>alert("'.$msj.'");</script>';// si existia un mensaje este lo imprime mediante 
        unset($_SESSION['msj']);//borra lo que habia en la variable.
    }

    require_once('../clases/clase_rol.php');//Trae el archivo clase_rol.php para instanciarlo
    require_once('../libreria/utilidades.php');//Trae el archivo utilidades.php para luego instanciarlo
    require_once('../clases/clase_bitacora.php');//Trae el archivo utilidades.php para luego instanciarlo
    $lobjRol=new clsRol;//Instancia la clase clsRol en $lobjRol, para poder usar sus metodos y atributos 
    $lobjUtil=new clsUtil;//Instancia la clase clsUtil en $lobjRol, para poder usar sus metodos 
    $lobjBitacora=new clsBitacora;//Instancia la clase clsUtil en $lobjRol, para poder usar sus metodos
    $menu='';//Declaro la variable $menu
    $lobjRol->set_Rol($_SESSION['idrol']);//Aquí se envia  mediante un metodo SET a la clase rol el idrol del usuario (que se guardo cuando se logueo en el sistema).
    $laModulos=$lobjRol->consultar_modulos();//Se consultan y se guardan en la variable $laModulos los módulos que tiene asignado el rol del usuario,

    $Acceso_servicio=false;//Para verificar que el usuario no entre a un servicio que no tiene asignado declaro una variable como false, y luego la cambiaré a true si alguno de los servicios que tiene asignado el usuario es igual a la direccion a la que está entrando.

    //Obtengo la carpeta del modulo
    $carpeta= explode('/',$vista); 
    if($carpeta[0]=='')
        $activo='active';
    // se arma en la variable $menu todo el menu que se le mostrará al usuario
    $menu.='<li class="'.$activo.'"><a href="intranet.php">Inicio</a></li>';    

    for($i=0;$i<count($laModulos);$i++) //Se recorre un ciclo para poder extraer los datos de cada uno de los módulos que tiene asignado el rol
    {

        $modulo=strtolower($lobjUtil->quitar_acentos($laModulos[$i][1]));        
        $activo=($modulo==$carpeta[0])?'active':'';

        $menu.='<li class="dropdown '.$activo.'" >'; 
        $menu.='<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">'.$laModulos[$i][1].'<span class="caret"></span></a>';//Aquí se guar el nombre del módulo y los servicios de este modulo se van a ir anidando a partir de aquí.
        $menu.='<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">';

        $laServicios=$lobjRol->consultar_servicios($laModulos[$i][0]); // aquí se consultan y guardan en la variable $laServicios los servicios que tiene registrado este módulo.
        for ($j=0; $j <count($laServicios) ; $j++) //Se recorre un ciclo para poder extraer los datos de cada uno de los servicios que tiene asignado el modulo para poder constuir el menú
        { 
            if($laServicios[$j][3])//Sí el servicio es visible para el menú lo agrega, sino no
            {    
                $menu.='<li><a href="?vista='.$laServicios[$j][2].'">'.$laServicios[$j][1].'</a></li>'; //aqui se van agregando cada uno de los servicios al menú.
            }
            if($vista=="" || $vista==$laServicios[$j][2])//aquí voy comparando los servicios del usuario con la direccion a la cual a entrado.
            {
                $Acceso_servicio=true;

            }                                       
        } 
        $menu.='</ul>'; 
        $menu.='</li>'; //se cierra la construccion del menú
    }


    $lcReal_ip=$lobjUtil->get_real_ip();//Ejecuta el función get_real_ip para saber la IP de el usuario.
    $lcDireccion=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];//obtiene la direccion en la que se encuentra el usuario
    $ldFecha=date('Y-m-d h:m');//obtiene la fecha actual

    $lobjBitacora->set_Datos($lcDireccion,$ldFecha,$lcReal_ip,'','','',$_SESSION['usuario'],$Acceso_servicio); //envia los datos a la clase bitacora
    $lnHecho=$lobjBitacora->registrar_bitacora();//registra los datos en la tabla tbitacora.

    if(!$Acceso_servicio)  //verifica si existe algún usuario logueado en el arreglo usuario de la variable $_SESSION
    {
        echo '<script>alert("Acceso Denegado! Usted no tiene el acceso permitido a este servicio del sistema.");window.location.href="intranet.php";</script>'; // Si no tiene asignado el servicio al cual intentó entrar, entonces lo manda al inicio de la intranet.! 
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--<link rel="SHORT ICON" href="../bootstrap-3/img/favicon.ico">
    <title>Modelo de seguridad</title>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="../bootstrap-3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bootstrap-3/css/style-intranet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bootstrap-3/datepicker/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../bootstrap-3/DataTables-1.10.2/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="../bootstrap-3/DataTables-1.10.2/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- EMPIEZA: MENU SUPERIOR -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
         <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img height="100%;" src="../bootstrap-3/img/logo"></a>-->
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav movil">
            <?php echo $menu;?>
          </ul>
          <div class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                <form name="form_intranet" action="../controlador/control_acceso.php" method="POST">
                    <input type="submit" name="salir"  class="btn btn-danger" value="Salir">
                </form>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <!-- FIN: MENU SUPERIOR -->
    <!-- EMPIEZA: CONTENEDOR -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- EMPIEZA: SIDEBAR -->
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <?php echo $menu;?>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- FIN: SIDEBAR -->
        <!-- EMPIEZA: CUERPO -->
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 main">
            <?php
                if(file_exists($vista.'.php')) //verifica el contenido de la variable vista.
                {
                        include($vista.'.php');// y si exite el archivo que trae este incluirá el cintenido
                }   
                else
                {
                    include_once("panel_inicio.php");// Si no exite o no tiene nada la variable vista entonces trae por defecto la vista panel_inicio.php
                }

            ?>       

          <!-- EMPIEZA: PIE -->
          <footer></footer>
          <!-- FIN: PIE -->
        </div>
        <!-- FIN: CUERPO -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- FIN: CONTENEDOR -->
    <!-- jQuery (necesario para los plugins de bootstrap) -->
    <!-- Incluye todos los plugins después de esta línea -->
    <script src="../bootstrap-3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../bootstrap-3/DataTables-1.10.2/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap-3/datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#filtro').dataTable();
    } );
        $(function () {
            $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover();
        });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Si alguien logra encontrar el error le agradezco me colabore.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y elimina los datos sensibles de BD `private $servidor = 'xxx';
    private $usuario = 'xxx';
    private $clave = 'xx';`

Comment: gracias por el comentario ya los acomode

Comment: ¿Has probado a subir un script más sencillo a 1&1? A mí me hizo perder bastante tiempo el tema de la codificación de caracteres en UTF8, hasta que probé con la codificación en ANSI y todo se resolvió.

Comment: Generalmente cuando las cosas funcionan en localhost, y luego hay problemas al migrarlas a un hosting compartido (que creo que es tu caso), los problemas muchas veces son de INFRAESTRUCTURA: 1) Distintas versiones del lenguaje que pueden ocasionar incompatibilidad segun el código utilizado 2) Conexión a la base de datos Te recomiendo que ejecutes un simple script que comprueba si la conexión a la BD es correcta, o no, como medida inicial.

Comment: En la línea del comentario de Andrés, parece que es un problema de configuración del hosting, incluso uno básico en el que no has subido el código al lugar correcto. Empieza por mostrar una página cualquiera (HTML incluso), luego por comprobar la conexión a la base de datos. Si todo funciona, también debería hacerlo tu código.

Comment: Debe ser por las versiones de php, te sugiero que cambies los las redirecciones con header por redirecciones con JS así: header('location: ../intranet.php'); por echo "<script> window.location = '../intranet.php';</script>", con eso evitas los errores e redirección y eso mismo debes hacer en todas las redirecciones que se hagan con header.

Comment: Solo para descartar intenta utilizar rutas  estáticas en los require_once, es decir cambia esto ('../clases/clase_usuario.php') por esto ('/var/www/html//clases/clase_usuario.php') obviamente considerando la ruta correcta en tu servidor.

Comment: mi recomendacion es que uses un host diferente a 1&1 ya que mi experiencia es mala y notado limitaciones hasta para usar phpmailer. y por lo tanto pueden existir otras restricciones propias del host. Si en tu maquina local funciona. Una prueba rapida es un phpinfo para ver diferencias entre la version local y remota pero aun asi mi recomendacion es cambiar de host